# Placing the pound symbol '£' in a Python plot axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, symbols, pound

Trying to place the pound symbol; '£', in a Python plot label had given me a headache.

Simple `plt.xlabel(r"$\pounds$")` does not seem to work.
Suggestion are really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does 'does not work' mean?  You have to make sure that you are using a font which has the needed glyphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, I just reinstalled LaTeX and seems to work now. That was very weird. I was getting an exception in Tkinter callback only with the pound symbol---spent a couple of hours on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try chr(163)

For future reference, go into your interpreter and type

```
>>> ord('£')
163
```